# Overriding custom init from super class

Tags: swift

I am trying to override custom init in my code as you can see I am creating `Player` class with default and custom init

```
class Player{
    //Properties
    var name : String
    var score : Int

    //Methods
    func description() -> String{
        return( "Player \(name) has score \(score)")
    }

    //Default Initiallizer
    init(){
        name = "Sohrab"
        score = 0
    }

    //Custom Initializer
    init(name : String, score : Int){
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
    }
}
```

and below I create `PremierPlayer` class

```
class PremierPlayer : Player {
    //Properties
    var memberLevel : String
    //Method
    override func description() -> String {
        let originalMessage = super.description()
        return ("\(originalMessage) is a \(memberLevel)")
    }
    //Default Initilizer
    override init() {
        memberLevel = "Gold"
        super.init()
    }
    //Custome Initilizer
    init(name: String, score: Int, memberLevel:String) {
        self.memberLevel = memberLevel
        super.init(name: <#String#>, score: <#Int#>)
    }
}
```

In Line `super.init(name: <#string#>, score: <#Int#>)` i got an error `ISSUE expected ',' separator`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of your (current version of) question is rather confusing, but if you are talking about this line:

```
super.init(name: <#String#>, score: <#Int#>)
```

... then you should replace `<#String#>` with just value of `String` and `<#Int#>` with `Int` types.  Those <#...#> are placeholders that XCode injects into code automatically for you to replace them with something sensible.